# Correct way to add teams to repository with curl

Tags: json, curl, github, post, put

Trying to add an org team to a repo but am unable to with the following:

```
curl -H "Authorization: token tokenID" -H "Content-Length: 0" -X put \
> -d "" https://url/api/v3/teams/23/repos/johndoe/repo-name
```

https://developer.github.com/v3/teams/#add-or-update-team-repository

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow. Please add the output of this command in the question by **edit**ing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fro the documentation and this [blog post](https://developer.github.com/changes/2017-08-30-preview-nested-teams/), you must provide a custom [media type](https://developer.github.com/v3/media/) in the Accept header:

```
application/vnd.github.hellcat-preview+json
```

With curl:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.github.hellcat-preview+json"...
```